# On the shape of a bounded, connected, radially symmetric domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: geometry

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded, connected, radially symemtric domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then is $\Omega$ necessarily a disk or an annulus?

Comment: The union of two annuli with the same center, with internal radius of the first bigger than the external radius of the second is also rotationally invariant with respect to any rotation around the common center.

Comment: @enzotib: but such a union is not connected.

Comment: $\Omega$ can also be the whole of $\Bbb R^2$, with optionally a disk removed.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the word

Comment: @TonyK, that's true, and thank you very much for your comment. Actually I'm more wondering if the domain is bounded, connected and radially symmetric, then is the domain necessarily a disk or an annulus? Sorry I should have added the boundedness assumption in the question.

Comment: Well you can always edit it. There's an `edit` button right there under the question.

Comment: @TonyK, Thanks, I've edited the question.